# CSS3 / Transition / change font color on grand-grand-grand parent over

Tags: html, css

I'm toying around with the CSS3 transition. I hope my question won't be too much noob and realistic :) Basically, whenever users mouse over some elements, I changed via css the color of the text.

Now the problem I have is that : I have a div box with the name of a product which is included in a span master element, which is also containing other data.
I would like to change the color of my product whenever users are over the master span elements.

In order to be more accurate here is the html code :

```
<span class="wrapper_productbox">
<a href="P1.html" title="" class="product-image"><img src="P1.jpg" width="210" height="210" alt=""/></a>
<div class="categoryProductBox">
    <div class="product-name">
        <a href="P1.html" title="PRODUCT NAME">PRODUCT NAME</a>
    </div>
</div></span>
```

So to sum up I would like to know if there is a way in CSS to change the font color of the product-name a element whenever users mouse over the master wrapper_productbox element  or the product-image a element.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two Choices

Each slightly different.

This will activate hovering over *even the white space* in the `.wrapper_product` box ([Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9TYhJ/8/)):

```
.wrapper_productbox:hover .product-name a {
    color: red;
}
```

This will only activate hovering over the two `a` tags *inside* the `.wrapper_productbox` ([Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9TYhJ/11/)):

```
a:hover + .categoryProductBox a,
.categoryProductBox a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Scotts,You totally made my day, it works very well! I was trying stupid things like .wrapper_productbox a:hover {} ... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/emQf3/) Used a bit of Jquery. If you prefer pure css you have to re constructure your html code a little bit and definitely to wrap your section with a div not span because the span will have a very short height and will not respond to your hover even.

```
$('.wrapper_productbox').hover(
    function() {
    $('.product-name a').css('color','green');
    },function() {
    $('.product-name a').css('color','#000');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Godinall, but I can't use JS for this (and even more Jquery, cause sadly, Prototype is already installed :/)